# Ruby On Rails: How to validate a form having file upload field with other fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, file-upload

I am new to Ruby on Rails(rails 3). I am having a form with three fields and among these three field, one field is to upload files(rar/tar/zip). I would like to know the way to validate (server side) such form that allow user:-

```
1. Fill in all three fields.
2. Uploaded file should be either rar/tar/zip.
3. Uploaded file should not exceed 2MB in size.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use the paperclip gem for uploading a file.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

there are validations like

```
validates_attachment :avatar, :presence => true,
  :content_type => { :content_type => "image/jpg" },
  :size => { :in => 0..10.kilobytes}
```

see https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip for more info.

Comment: Which gem i will need to add?

Comment: paperclip gem. use the above link.

Comment: Is it possible to get that gem by adding something in GEM file... something like "gem paperclip"

Comment: gems are specified in the Gemfile. add 'gem "paperclip"' in Gemfile and do bundle install. please read RoR 3 functioning.

Comment: I have added the code validates_attachment :application_path, :presence => true, :with => %r{\.(rar|tar|zip)$}i,:size => { :in => 2000.kilobytes} but i get error "undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass"... Any suggestion? Here application_path is my field name

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code, to use this you have to use **[paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)**

```
validates_attachment_size :upload, :less_than => 2.megabytes,
                  :with => %r{\.(rar|tar|zip)$}i
```

Comment: After adding this into my model i got the error "undefined method `validates_attachment_size'"

Comment: @neeraj i missed to type, you have to use paperclip gem for this.. paperclip gem is best for file uploads and all its requirements

Comment: Can i add that GEM by adding some code in to my gem file... like "gem paperclip" ?

Comment: I installed paperclip and i get the error "undefined method `application_path_file_size' for #<ApplicationInstance:0x000000041489b8>" here application_path is the name of my field.... how to fix this?

Comment: @neeraj In the general case, you can use Object#send to call a method based on a symbol (which you can get from a string using to_sym):

send(application_path.to_sym, @application)

Comment: @neeraj But in this case, because your dynamic string is simple enough, Rails has a built-in method to do this, url_for:

url_for(@application)

Comment: I am sorry i could not understand why you are referring to URL. It seems you might be confused with the word "application_path". This is just a field name of my table that will save the path of the uploaded file. So what changed i will have to make to run your code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24300/discussion-between-raj-inevitable-and-neeraj)

Comment: I am there and waiting for your response.

Answer (score 0):

[Validating Presence](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#presence)

[Validating format](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#format)

For size, I think you could figure something out from that Rails guide or just by Googling.

To clarify, in the model that the user is updating, you want to put validations for presence (as outlined in that link) for the three attributes. Then a format validation for the zip-file field. And similarly for size, when you find or create an appropriate validation.